# Why doesn't socket.close() free up the bound port?

Tags: java, sockets

I am sending a single message to a TCP server and after running it once I get `java.net.BindException: Address already in use` errors when I try to run it again. I figured that the socket would be unbound; I can't find anything specifically saying that it does in the documentation, though. How do I free up the port, am I not ending the transaction properly here? Here is my client:

```
public class TcpPingClient {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      Socket tcpSocket = new Socket();
      tcpSocket.bind(new InetSocketAddress("192.168.1.2", 45030));
      tcpSocket.connect(new InetSocketAddress("192.168.1.2", 1211));
      DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(tcpSocket.getOutputStream());
      out.writeBytes("oh hey\n");
      tcpSocket.close();
   }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to bind your local socket to a specific port, that is (usually) unnecessary

Comment: @DiegoCNascimento Exactly, and usually that random local port works just fine.

Comment: @DiegoCNascimento I'm not wrong. It is not necessary for a TCP client to call bind() or to bind itself to a specific port, which is exactly what you said above was necessary. You've just now said the same thing yourself. Make up your mind.

Comment: Well, there's no need to bind it to a local port yourself, the system just picks a random and free local port and bind.

Comment: @EJP you forget one :) If you want to say that please do it without directing to me, I rewrite my comment, and I think it's more clear now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is unbound, but waiting for timeout in case the other end need some data buffered on the senders end.  If you want to re-use a port without waiting for this to happen you can use

```
socket.setReuseAddress(true);
```

This must be set before you attempt to bind.

In short, this is how TCP is implemented, not a feature of Java.

Comment: I don't think this is a good approach as it's throwing the TIME_WAIT state functionality away. If it need, the OS can/or not have a way to change the TIME_WAIT period. In the case of Windows NT based for example http://www.pctools.com/guides/registry/detail/878/. Anyway I think a good application difficult will need to change or handle TIME_WAIT.

Answer (score 6):

You might want to read about [TCP protocol operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Protocol_operation), especially check out the [TCP state diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Tcp_state_diagram_fixed.svg).

When a socket is closed, it ends up in the state `TIME_WAIT`, and while it's there no other socket may be bound to the same address.

That is, unless the first (now closed) socket had the "reuse address" flag set. This flag allows another socket to be bound to the same address as an existing socket in the `TIME_WAIT` state.

Answer (score 1):

The socket stays in TIME_WAIT state for a while after you closed it. It is done by the OS to make sure that the communication has been finished.